# Django admin add template: combine fields for saving in DB

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm new to Python and Django, and I need help from experienced pythonists. I have a model Unit like that:

```py
class Unit(models.Model):
    unit_type = models.CharField("Unit type", max_length=25)
    content = models.TextField()
```

I want to be able to add some units with Admin panel. But in the content field I need to have a JSON-serialized object, containing a bunch of data, so I want to let users to add that data via ordinary fields, and combine them in JSON programmatically and save in the content. But when I try to register this model in Admon like that:

```py
class UnitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['unit_type', 'url', 'name']}),
    ]

admin.site.register(Unit, UnitAdmin)
```

I get an error:

```py
FieldError at /admin/cms/unit/add/
Unknown field(s) (name, url) specified for Unit. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class UnitAdmin.
```

Can I somehow collect more data in my admin panel than I need to save in a database?

**Update**

I managed to create additional fields via modelForm class, thanks to Alex's suggestion. But when I save the model, I don't know how to assign value to the content field. My code is like that now:

```py
class UnitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = forms.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        model = Unit
        fields = ["name", "url", "unit_type"]


class UnitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = UnitForm
```

I know, how to get the name and url values in the modelForm class, but I can't assign them to the content field of Unit model. How should I do that?

Comment: i think you should use `JSONField(default=dict, blank=True)` instead of models.TextField(), for users just create a new field in the form.

Comment: @alex, but it's not very good to force someone to write a JSON in a field. It's more convinient to allow people to fill normal fields, and combine them into a JSON in backend, I think.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. The json field was for you, for normal users you just create normal fields in the form, then you manipulate the posted data in you view and save it in the jsonfield, at least that's what i understood you want, also why don't you just create a separate UnitType model with url_field, name_field and foreign key to Unit model?

Comment: But in order to create normal fields in the form, I need to have them in the Unit model, if I get the Admin panel features right? I got how to exclude a field from showing up in the add template, but I do not want to have the normal fields separately saved in my database.

Comment: no, you can also create fields in the form that are not in the model, for ex. you have model Unit, you make a modelform and also create a field there `name` as `forms.Charfield`, in your view you would access it `form.cleaned_data.get('name')`

Comment: I managed to create additional fields via modelForm class, but I don't know how to  pass their values to the content field. Please, take a look at my Update.

Comment: It is called initial value. You can do it in __init__, something like self.fields[‘name’].initial = ‘something’. Newly created fields in form already have an argument called initial and you can pass it after max_length

Comment: In __init__ of UnitForm? There is no "content" field in the form. I want to generate it programmatically, using data from the extra fields. I could get that data, but have no idea how to pass to in the content :( I feel like going the wrong way more and more...